# How to write Cypher query with gremlin groovy?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

```
MATCH (nginx1111:Service {name:"nginx1111", ip:"1.1.1.1"})
MATCH (host2222:Host {hostname:"host2222", ip:"2.2.2.2"})
MATCH p=(nginx1111)-[*{type:"upstream"}]->(host2222)
```

How to write the above Cypher query with gremlin groovy?

Comment: To help others who may have a similar question it would be great if you could add a more precise title and also add some words about what your Cypher query does.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get all paths between 2 vertices:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Service').has('name','nginx1111').has('ip','1.1.1.1')
.repeat(outE().has('type', 'upstream').inV().simplePath())
.until(hasLabel('Host').has('name','host2222').has('ip','2.2.2.2'))
.path()
```